# Map matrix elements to {0, 1} values in EJML

Tags: ejml

I would like to turn a matrix of non-negative integers to a binary matrix. For example, given the following input matrix:

```
2 3
0 1
```

It should the following output matrix:

```
1 1
0 1
```

I think this is similar to a map operation, so pseudocode-wise this operation is equivalent to `mapElements(x -> (x > 0) ? 1 : 0)` or simply `mapNonZeroes(x -> 1)`.

A possible approach is to unfurl the non-zero elements of the matrix to triplets with the value set to 0/1 and rebuild the matrix from the triplets. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me what worked is to directly access the `nz_values` storage field, and map the values myself.

```java
public void normalizeMatrix(DMatrixSparseCSC m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.nz_length; i++) {
        m.nz_values[i] = Math.min(m.nz_values[i], 1.0);
    }
}
```